# Organising the Windows 10 Start Menu - Cannot move (or delete) Groove Music icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, start-menu

On my new Windows 10 (v1803) PC there are a bunch of strange pre-installed applications, like `Groove Music`. These clutter up the Start Menu > All Apps list with no hierarchy, just all on the same level. I'd like to organise these icons into separate, logical folders on the Start Menu.

[image: Groove Music icon creating clutter]

Searching online I've found several articles describing how you can (attempt to) uninstall these Windows Store applications, but nothing about how to move or remove the icons. I'm not (yet!) looking to uninstall the app, just to organise the Start Menu into something more logical and less cluttered.

In previous versions of Windows, a user could create a folder called (say) `Windows Stuff` in the appropriate path. Then you could drag the icons into this folder. After acknowledging the UAC prompt the icon has moved. Great! With these new Windows 10 "Universal" applications, however, I can't seem to do anything with them.

Things I have tried:

- Navigated to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. No icons or `.lnk` files for these Windows metro apps are visible.
- Navigated to `C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. Likewise, none of these metro apps appear.
- Used `WIN+R` and then `shell:AppsFolder` to actually view installed applications. Here I can see the `ZuneMusic` application (see below), but I can neither delete, uninstall or move it.

[image: ZuneMusic application]

- Tried grabbing the icon directly in the Start Menu and dragging it...but a `No Entry` symbol appears and the icon cannot be moved or removed.
- If you right-click the icon there is no option to `Move` or `Delete` the icon (nor even to `Uninstall` the application, although this is not what I'm looking to do).

How do you get control over the Start Menu in Windows 10 (in a similar way to Windows 7 or Windows XP)?

#### Update

After many different searches, I stumbled on [this old article](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/organize-remove-all-apps-windows-10-start-menu/) which suggests organising these strange "Universal" Windows Store apps may not be possible.

The article is ~3 years old and from an earlier version of Windows 10 so hopefully (a) Microsoft have fixed this in v1803 and/or (b) any reader knows the technical steps required to organise these applications that the original author did not.

Answer (score 1):

Start menu customizations you could do in previous versions of Windows are no longer
possible since Microsoft abandoned the Windows 7 Start menu.

To return these types of customizations you need to look for third party products.

Here are some such free or freemium products:

- [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net/)
  No longer actively developed but works fine. Does not support tiles. My preference.
- [Start Menu Reviver](https://www.reviversoft.com/start-menu-reviver/)
- [Start Menu X](https://www.startmenux.com/index.html)  (freemium)

Comment: Hmm, that is consistent with online searches. I used `Classic Shell` on an earlier Windows 8.1 PC and this product is to be recommended. Shame is, though, that you will lose the  `Pinned tiles` area of the Windows 10 `Start Menu` which is rather good and can be customised. Microsoft has done a bad job with these "modern" Store apps. They're mostly clunky, chunky and awful and have zero customisation options. Some cannot be removed at all and the ones you can remove require steps that will be daunting to the average user.

Comment: Start Menu Reviver seems to have some form of tiles, although I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure it's possible to remove only the icon of Windows Store Apps...

Anyway, you can completely remove it by opening a PowerShell window as administrator and typing:

*Get-AppxPackage -allusers *zunemusic* | Remove-AppxPackage*

This can be used to get rid of all the "utilities" forcibly installed with W10, just in changing the package name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Searching on the web will find many articles describing how to uninstall Windows Store apps (such as your example), but the question specifically asks how you might move the icon only and that uninstall is *not* under consideration. Essentially, this is about the `Start Menu` and not about any specific application like `Groove Music`.